# Simple reverse engineering exercice using Cutter

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm currently learning to do some basic reverse engineering of binary files using Cutter. The program i'm struggling on test if the password entered as argument is correct, if not, return an error message. I have some serious gap in assembly and I can't figure out the password on this one. I've worked on it for some times and arrived at a point where i'm stuck..

Here is the decompiled code, the test of the password happend during the while/if iterations so what's before is just to give some contex.

```
undefined4 main(int param_1,int param_2){
    undefined4 uVar1;
    size_t sVar2;
    undefined4 local_21;
    undefined4 local_1d;
    undefined local_19;
    char *local_18;
    int local_14;
    undefined4 *local_10;

    local_10 = &param_1;
    local_14 = 0;
    if (param_1 == 2) {
          local_21 = 0x776f7264;
          local_1d = 0x70617373;
          local_19 = 0;
          local_18 = *(char **)(param_2 + 4);
          sVar2 = strlen(local_18);
          if (sVar2 < 8) {
                uVar1 = 0xffffffff;
          }
          else {
                while (local_14 < 8) {
                      if ((int)local_18[local_14] + 1 != (int)*(char                   
                          *)((int)&local_21 + local_14)) {
                              puts("Wrong password.");
                              return 0xffffffff;
                      }
                      local_14 = local_14 + 1;
                }
                puts("Access granted.");
                uVar1 = 0;
                }
          }
    else {
          puts("One and only one argument PLS.");
          uVar1 = 0xffffffff;
    }
    return uVar1;
}
```

UPDATE 1, What I know from my guess and the help of others :

- The program doesn't return any error message if the password given is less than 8 character. (If it is >=8 it says that the password is incorrect). I do think that the password must be 8 character.
- The password is probably in hexadecimal. Why do I think that ? the var used during the verification of the password (local_21 = 776f7264 = word) is exactly 8 characters and we do iterate 8 times in the verification.
- There's some kind of shift involved since we are testing (local_18[local_14] + 1) with local_18 the argument i entered and local_14 the iterator being incremented in the end of the while. From what I've been told that it will shift the password i enter and it need to be the same as (int)*(char *)((int)&local_21 + local_14)) but i can't figure out what is it.
- So If my though are correct, i need to find a 8 caracter Hexadecimal from which i'll shift the characters (remplace b by a for example) to match what i'm trying to translate " (int)*(char *)((int)&local_21 + local_14)) "

I'm trying to find out if I'm right..

UPDATE 2, Here is a screen of [the assembly tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwm1o.png) and the [while section zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbOxX.png).

I also commented it below but as you can see there's some section where I just can't understand what's happening :

```
VARS : 
local_21 = 0x776f7264 ; (String) word used in password comparaison
local_1d = 0x70617373 ;(String) pass but unused
local_14 = 0 ;iterator
local_18 = argv[1] (it's the string given as an argument, let's 
           assume i've entered "examples")

- mov edx, dword [local_14] -->  load the value of local_14 into edx 
                                 local_14 = 0

- mov eax, dword[local_18] --> load the function argument into the 
                               register 
                               local_18 = examples


- add eax, edx --> add the value 0 to our password (does it means we 
                   add 0 to the address of our input or directly to 
                   the input ?)

- movzx eax, byte[eax] --> get the first character in eax (is he 
                           taking the hexa character 7 ?

- movsx eax, al --> ?

- lea ecx, [eax + 1] --> load the address of [eax+1] into eax (don't 
                         know what is in eax+1..)

- lea edx, [local_21] --> load the address of local_21 in edx
                          it is 0x776f7264 so what does it stock ? Do 
                          I considerer this as a value or as an 
                          address?

- mov eax, dword[local_14] --> load the value of local_14 (0) into 
                             eax, so 0x0 ?

- add eax, edx -> we add local_14 (0) to eax, so do we have 0x776f7264

- movzx eax, byte[eax] --> exact same thing as before.

- movsx eax, al --> same as before

- cmp ecx, eax --> we compare ecx et eax (eax=?, ecx = [eax+1] = ?)

- add dword [local_14], 1 --> we add 1 to (local_14), it became 1 (our 
                            iterator)

- cmp dword [local-14], 7 --> we compare our iterator with with 7, if 
                              it is lower we continue 

- we start again from the start
```

I have trouble understand if 0x776f7264 is actually an address or just the value in eax. So when i add 1, what is actually happend (2,3 etc..) ? Do i had this directly to the hexa or do I consider adding it to a character ?
Like 77 = w so i add 1 to w and it gives me x

I'm really sorry if i have poorly explained my problem and will do my best to answer any questions regarding my post.

Thanks a lot and have a nice day !

Comment: `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx();` - unfortunate for you that someone gave you an x86 32-bit PIE to deal with.  They have to load a pointer from the GOT for access to static data (like global vars and string literals, e.g. the error message) because PC-relative addressing on x86 wasn't introduced until x86-64.  Looks like your decompiler did a decent job, but that's why you have crap like `unaff_EBX + 0x17f`.

Comment: Thanks for very much for the answer.. I can still manage to find it using dirrectly the assembly code no ?

Comment: Some remarks: 1) you can ignore the `movsx eax, al` instructions those are just sign extending `char` to `int` 2) The `lea ecx, [eax + 1]` is used as simple arithmetic, i.e. `ecx=eax+1`. It's not dereferenced as an address. 3) The code just seems to check that the input shifted by 1 letter is `password`, that is `if (input[i] + 1 != password[i]) fail();`

Comment: Thanks you very much for the anwser, so where byte[eax] is called it actually take only caracter and add 1 to it ? So it shift the entire word by 1 caracter ? I just want to be sure that I got it ! I'm gonna try !!

Comment: Of course you can find everything using the asm code (and symbol table if necessary, `objdump -drwC -Mintel` or whatever other disassembler that will include relocations if any), it's just more complicated.  In a non-PIE the string address would be right there as an absolute 32-bit address, not messing around with another register and adding a relative offset from the GOT or loading an address from the GOT.

Comment: @Jester Not working so far :/ Don't think it's the solution sadly

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I found the password, it was acutally drowssap shifted by one letter. So you were totally right but I had trouble to understand the values of the hex (local_21 = 0x776f7264; local_1d = 0x70617373)  When I tried to convert them I had 'pass' and 'word' for those values but it seems like depending on " little endian " and " big endian " the order can be shifter so that's why I couldn't get the correct answer !